# Boyd & Vandenberghe, exercise 4.4(d)

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

From Boyd & Vandenberghe's *Convex Optimization*:

> Suppose $G=\{Q_1,\cdots Q_k\}\subset R^{n\times n}$ is a group. We say that the function $f$ is $G$ invariant or symmetric with respect to $G$  if $f(Q_ix)=f(x)$ holds for all $x$ and $i\in \{1,\cdots k\}$. We define $\bar{x}=(\frac{1}{k})\sum_{i=1}^kQ_ix$, which is the average of $x$ over its $G$-orbit. We define the  fixed subspace of $G$ as
>
> $F=\{x, \text{such that } Q_ix=x, i\in\{1,\cdots k\}\}$.
>
> Part d: As an example, suppose $f$ is convex and symmetric for every permutation $P$. Show that if $f$ has a minimizer then it has a minimizer of the form $\alpha [1, 1,\cdots 1]$.

Its solution is as follows:

Suppose $x^*$ is a minimizer of $f$. Let $\bar{x}=\frac{1}{n!}\sum_{P}Px^*$ where the sum is over all permutations. Since $\bar{x}$ is invariant under any permutation we conclude that $\bar{x}=\alpha [1,\cdots,1]$ for some $\alpha$ on real line. (I really do not understand this last sentence how to show that it its true. Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.)

Comment: All the last sentence is saying is that since the vector $\bar{x}$ never changes if you permute (re-order) its elements, it must be a vector where every element is the same. Can you show this? (If not, consider what would happen if two of the elements happened to be different and you applied a certain permutation of the elements...) Also, make sure you understand why $\bar{x}$ is invariant under any permutation!

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth thank you so much for the prompt response.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth yes they have explained it in the part (a) of the question. But I have a little confusion about that too. I think that it is assumed in the solution that for a fixed $Q_j$, $Q_jQ_i$ is different for all $i$'s. Is it true?

Comment: @FrankMoses (d) is a special case. For a general group you don't have the result for (d).

Comment: @ThinkingTorus yes i understand that. But is it true for general group that for fix $Q_j$ the product $Q_jQ_i$ is different for all $i$?

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth The solution is misleading. It's not $\bar x$ that is invariant. It's f that is invariant. Although $\bar x$ is indeed invariant, you only get that after the conclusion it's a constant times $[1,...1]$.

Comment: @FrankMoses Group theory time: suppose ab = ac, do we know b=c? Yes, multiply on the left by $a^{-1}$. So yes, if b!=c, then ab!=ac.

Comment: @ThinkingTorus thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put all the permutations in a matrix, with each permutation as a row. You take sums column-wise. Do all the sums equal? Yes, because each column contains the same number of each element of $x^*$. Convince yourself that the number permutations with $x^*_1$ in slot 1 is the the same as that with $x^*_1$ in slot 2, and so on ...